# Save video to storage without having it show up in photos gallery (Swift iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, video, core-data, video-player

### Problem

Hi,
I am developing an app that manages different "lessons" within CoreData. Each of these lesson entities has (among other attributes) a thumbnail image and a video. Both of these *have* to be saved locally and I'd prefer it if they didn't show up in the phones gallery app, as the user should only be able to delete them together with the whole lesson entity. This might sound stupid to you, but for the purpose of this app, it is important. The lessons will either be downloaded or added by the user himself.
The images, I can save within CoreData as binary files and they won't show up in gallery, but I want to play the video within an AVPlayer, which (to my understanding) needs a URL. Thus, I have to save the video as a normal video file and then save the URL within CoreData. I don't have much experience with iOS devices overall as I come from Android, so to my understanding, if I save the video in the file system, it will probably get indexed and show up in the gallery - which I don't want.

### Tl;Dr:

My question: Is there a way to save a video or its reference inside CoreData so it can be easily played in my app, without having it show up within the photo gallery? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving a video onto the storage will not display in the Photo Gallery, in iOS/iPad OS the Photo Gallery requires another set of permissions and you have to specifically save in the Foto Gallery.

I would recommend to use your app isolated storage as the user can not see the files with 3rd apps or even Apple's File Manager.

For that take a look into [FileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager) class witch allows you to save files onto the disk.

I leave this tutorial as starting point [iOS FileManager in Swift](https://medium.com/@javedmultani16/ios-filemanager-in-swift-409c1c24699b)